# Project Tab shows error icons with Netbeans 8.2 and Lombok 1.16.ANY

Tags: netbeans-8, lombok

Well, I've just updated from Netbeans 8.1 to 8.2 but the Netbean's Project tab shows compiler error icons as the following:

[image]

I've tried all 1.16.X versions of Lombok. None of them have worked.
I've also tried to delete the `~/.cache/netbeans/8.2/` folder, but it has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think Netbeans 8.2 uses an (unreleased) version of jdk9. The lombok developers are working on jdk9 support, but that's not yet finished. See if you can configure Netbeans to use a different jdk for compilation.

Comment: No, I think that's not the case. Here's running with Java 8.

Comment: Actually my project compiles but Netbeans still shows errors on classes